# returning results from two different max dates as columns of the same result set

Tags: mysql

I have written the following MySQL query which successfully returns a list of subjects and the most recent value as of a specific date:

```
SELECT t1.subject, t1.judgement AS judgement1, t1.assessor AS assessor1, t1.dateAchieved AS dateAchieved1 
FROM `wwlpredictedoveralljudgements` t1 
WHERE pupilID='115137218853' && t1.dateAchieved = (
SELECT MAX(t2.dateAchieved) 
FROM `wwlpredictedoveralljudgements` t2 
WHERE t1.pupilID = t2.pupilID && t1.subject=t2.subject && dateAchieved<='2018-01-25 00:00:00')
```

It works exactly as I need. What I want to do though is have an additional 3 columns:
judgement2, assessor2, dateAchieved2 
from a 2nd specified date. 
I've read-up and tried various joins and sub-queries, but I've not managed to get a working result.

The result looks like this:

[image: results]

I need an additional 3 columns, but with a second cut off date in a second MAX selection. Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Question is unclear without table structure/example data and excepted output read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056

Comment: It isn't clear if your existing query returns one row or many or if the enriched query would return one row or many.

Comment: output included now. Required output would have 3 further columns, returned from querying a 2nd date.

Comment: Question1: how are the new 3 columns related to your original working query? by pupilID &&subject too? Question 2: is the second cutoff date a MAX(dateachieved) too?

Answer (score 0):

solved. Solution for anyone else with a similar issue... left join back to the same table with a 2nd WHERE condition.

```
SELECT t1.pupilID, t1.subject, t1.judgement AS judgement1, t1.assessor AS assessor1, t1.dateAchieved AS dateAchieved1 , t3.judgement AS judgement2, t3.assessor AS assessor2, t3.dateAchieved AS dateAchieved2 
FROM `wwlpredictedoveralljudgements` t1 
LEFT JOIN wwlpredictedoveralljudgements t3 ON t3.pupilID=t1.pupilID && t3.subject=t1.subject
WHERE t1.pupilID='084601821376' && t1.dateAchieved = (
SELECT MAX(t2.dateAchieved) FROM `wwlpredictedoveralljudgements` t2 
WHERE t1.pupilID = t2.pupilID && t1.subject=t2.subject && dateAchieved<='2018-01-25 00:00:00') && t3.dateAchieved = (
SELECT MAX(t4.dateAchieved) 
FROM `wwlpredictedoveralljudgements` t4 WHERE t3.pupilID = t4.pupilID && t3.subject=t4.subject && dateAchieved<='2018-03-25 00:00:00')
```